# SugarCRM server Dependencies Document for Linux

Tags: php, linux, apache, sugarcrm

We are upgrading Apache and PHP on our servers. As fresh apache is compiled one, is there any specific list of modules required to run SugarCRM smoothly?

What I need is 
1. Specific List of Apache modules required for SugarCRM
2. Specific List of PHP modules required for SugarCRM

Purpose: To avoid unnecessary load on Server. Server is dedicated for SugarCRM application.

Any help or suggestions are highly appreciated.

Environment Details:
RedHat Enterprise linux 5

SugarCRM Enterprise Edition 6.2.4
Oracle 11g
PHP 5.5.6
Apache 2.4.6

Regards,
Sagar Salunkhe

Comment: imap, curl, gd2, bz2, mysql/mysqli/pdo not 100% on which it uses these days not looked at sugar in a while it was crap, zip, openssl

Comment: @Dave -- thanks for your quick response.. i think ldap is also there.. any link that specifies exact modules???

Comment: you don't really need ldap unless you want it to authenticate against your activedirectory / login services. if sugar is managing its own userlist ldap is not required.  imap is only required if you want to hook it into users mailboxes to auto pull back mails etc or you want to use the ticketing system.

Comment: yeah right, even mbstring is also requires to use reports module. just like this I require list of modules to be enabled.